# Why does this query fail when running on ODBC table but work on local tables?

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc

I have a `MainUserTable` which I am trying to update with a `NewUserTable` which contains any new users and any data that has changed for existing users.

I have a SQL query being run in an access 2013 database to update `MainUserTable`, which is an ODBC connected Access web app table. It should add new users if they don't exist and update any data that has changed for users who already exist in the table.

```
UPDATE NewUserTable 
       LEFT JOIN MainUserTable ON NewUserTable.Username = MainUserTable.Username 
       SET MainUserTable.[First Name] = [NewUserTable].[First Name]
```

This works as expected when I run this on local tables, creating new records for new users and updating existing users, however when it is run against the ODBC table I get the following error:

> ODBC--call failed.
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] - Invalid argument value (#0)

This error only occurs when there are new users in the `NewUserTable`; i.e a record with a `NewUserTable.Username` that does not match a `MainUserTable.Username`. If it is not inserting any new records, just updating records it works fine.

Comment: Wait... are you getting new entries created in MainUserTable when there are new entries in NewUserTable (locally)? Is the local DB and mdb or accdb?

Comment: Yes.  The local database is accdb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing here is actually contrary to the way I would expect an "update" command to work. If it was intended to insert a record as need be, I would have expected ANSI to call it something like "updateorinsert" or "addupdate".

I would do it as two steps.

1. An insert of the missing entries from `NewUserTable`
2. An update of `MainUserTable` with a straight inner join of `MainUserTable` and  `NewUserTable`

Why your code works locally may be an artifact of how MS implemented `update`. Kind of like when you can update or add to query that's bound to a form that is the join of two tables. I dislike that behaviour because, to me, the rules of when it will and won't work are cryptic. And when you move to a different database that pattern no longer works and you have to rewrite code or retain people.